# Наблюдение за транзакциями

Tags: java, база-данных, java-ee, wildfly, ejb

Имеется Java EE приложение (на сервере WildFly), работа с базой идёт через предоставляемый сервером DataSource. Каким образом можно произвести наблюдения, за происходящими транзакциями в ходе выполнения запроса к EJB компоненту? То есть, произвести дебаг транзакций, грубо говоря.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для наблюдения за транзакциями в *WildFly* можно использовать, например, *Narayana Transaction Analyser* (*NTA*) (http://narayana.io/downloads/index.html). Несмотря на некоторую "древность" последней версии (апрель 2014 года) и альфа-статус, продукт вполне работоспособен и выдаваемая им информация является достаточно полезной.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо. И ещё вопрос, можно ли как-то логировать транзакции?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, можно, но сам не пробовал - не было необходимости. Почитайте здесь: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/chap-Transaction_Subsystem.html#About_Transaction_Log_Messages, вероятно, подойдёт.

Comment: Благодарю. Пытался сам нагуглить, но не получилось.